# Riggify hand points down when IK handle is moved hand points to ground

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm working on a rig in riggify. When I move the IK rig the hand points to the ground which makes me have to rotate the wrist. When I rotate the wrist it rotates the forearm. I've turned off inherit rotation for the forearm tweak which helped a little bit when I do the same with the wrist it breaks the rig. Then I tried turning the influence on the hand joint down to zero which fixed where the hand was pointing but once again turned off the rotation controls.

Is there a way to either fix where the hand points when moving the ik handle or can I control stop the tweak at the wrist affecting the forearm? Any help will be greatly appreciated! [image]